# Switching out components in vue on a click event

Tags: vue.js, components

I am making a website that has a storytelling purpose. When the user clicks on something, a new layout will be presented, either a video that covers the whole screen or a picture. When the button next is pressed it has to show something new but the url has to stay the same.

I have been trying to work with components in vue, but I don't understand how to handle clicks to rewrite the page to something else.

I have a file `start.vue` with a template in it for start screen and also `firstvideo.vue` (for example) with its own template. How do I connect these two with a click event?

`App.vue`-file:

```
<template>
        <div id="app">
            <keep-alive>
                <component :is="selectedComponent"></component>
            </keep-alive>
        </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Start from './components/Start.vue'
    import FlyingVideo from './components/FlyingVideo.vue'

    export default {
        name: 'app',
        components: {
            Start, FlyingVideo
        },
        data (){
            return {
                selectedComponent: 'Start'
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

`Start.vue`-file:

```
<template>
    <span>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <button @click="selectedComponent = 'FlyingVideo'">Start</button>
    </span>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Start'
    }
</script>
```

`FlyingVideo.vue`-file:

```
<template>
    <span>
        <h1>Video</h1>
        <p>Video coming soon</p>
    </span>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'FlyingVideo'
    }
</script>
```

From the code that I have written i get to display the first component from Start.vue but I can't click and display the video.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! You may get more helpful answers if you can share some of the code you've tried already and show us how it hasn't worked for you yet.

Comment: Thank you! I have now added the code to the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do without the view router. In your App.js component you will initialize all your components, and display them or not according to your state.
It would be better to use vuex to manage your store in this case.

So you can do something like this

```
<component1 v-if="toDisplayComponent1"></component1>
<component2 v-if="toDisplayComponent2"></component2>
...
```

And into your component use the $store to mutate toDisplayComponent1 ...

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways you can handle this. `vue-router` is certainly possible, but isn't really necessary for what you're doing, especially if you don't want the url updating.

In this example, we have a list of components that you'll render, and update the component that's actually rendered by changing the page number.

app.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>This is my Vue App</h2>
    <component :is="componentViews[page]"></component>
    <button v-on:click="updateComponent">Next</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script type="text/javascript">
  module.exports = {
    data: function() {
      return {
        page: 0,
        componentViews: ['start', 'first-video']
      }
    },
    methods: {
      updateComponent: function(){
          this.page += 1;
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Live example here: https://jsfiddle.net/ebbishop/u7dpwv3b/

Comment: This seems doable in one file, but since I have several files and can't keep the button displayed all the time I run into trouble.

Comment: @daria This solution doesn't assume a single file (though in jsfiddle, I realize it is all in a single file). No matter how many files you have, the root component/app can have the button to page through child components. If that's not how you want it to work, how does the user change from one page to the next? Seems that there needs to be some kind of UI to do so.